# Question about dilations of a set and open balls

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B(0, \frac{r}{2^n} )$. Is it true that

$$ B(0, \frac{r}{2^n} )  = \frac{1}{2^n} B(0, r ) \quad?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly right. A point $x$ is in both of these sets if and only if it has the property $\|x\|<r/2^n$.

Comment: Suppose $n=1$, the left is a ball of radius r/2 about 0. The right is 1/2 a ball of radius r. I can imagine different sets representing 1/2 a ball. So must they be identical?

Comment: By $1/2^nB(0,r)$ I think the OP means $\{x/2^n\,:\,x\in B(0,r)\}$.